# Why is useState not working correctly or am I missing something so Obvious?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm new to react and just read documentation on useState. So I started trying it in playground, but looks like It doesn't work. When I tried logging value of temp, it is empty.
Example below:

[link to playground](https://playcode.io/893227)

Comment: setState is async method, you are printing the value just after the setting. Click it one more time and you should see the value as expected.

Comment: First time is empty , additional clicks are ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the useEffect hook inorder to print state value. `setState` is async. If you want to print the new `temp` value, you will need to use the useEffect hook and put a dependency `temp` on useEffect. This is so whenever `temp` changes the useEffect would run a callback.

For more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState('')

  const handleClick = () => {
    setTemp('Value changes')
 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Temp val is ",temp)
  }, [temp])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2 onClick={()=> handleClick()}>Should set temp after clicking here </h2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

https://playcode.io/893227